# Hosting web app bundled with webpack

Tags: javascript, web-applications, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I have built a web app on top of Stephen Grider's [ReduxSimpleStarter](https://github.com/StephenGrider/ReduxSimpleStarter), a react-redux boilerplate. It uses Webpack for bundling. Now I want to host my app on [firebase](https://www.firebase.com/). When I do so, the bundling doesn't work, and I am left with a simple [index.html](https://agathos.firebaseapp.com/).

Could someone please explain how I trigger Webpack bundling for an app that is not locally hosted?

These files might be relevant, though I am not sure.

```
    //package.json
{
      "name": "testapp",
      "version": "0.0.0",
      "description": "testapp",
      "main": "index.js",
      "scripts": {
        "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
      },
      "author": "",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "babel-core": "^6.2.1",
        "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.1.18",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.1.18",
        "webpack": "^1.12.9",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^1.14.0"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "axios": "^0.9.1",
        "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.1.18",
        "jquery": "^2.2.0",
        "lodash": "^3.10.1",
        "material-ui": "^0.14.4",
        "react": "^0.14.3",
        "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
        "react-redux": "^4.0.0",
        "react-tap-event-plugin": "^0.2.2",
        "redux": "^3.0.4",
        "redux-promise": "^0.5.1"
      }
    }
```

.

```
//webpack.config

module.exports = {
  entry: [
    './src/index.js'
  ],
  output: {
    path: __dirname,
    publicPath: '/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [{
      exclude: /node_modules/,
      loader: 'babel'
    }]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    contentBase: './'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution. Include `"webpack": "^1.12.9"` in the `dependencies` object. Then, change

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js"
      },
```

to

```
"scripts": {
        "start": "node ./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
      },
```

Comment: I am also trying to bundle my app using webpack and then run it using `firebase serve`, any tips?

Answer (score 0):

I know it is answered but this is an additional note to the answer which will help a lot.

**Tip 1:**
When you deploy the application on *Firebase* and try to access browser (especially *React,Redux*) application you may get an error saying :

```
can not find module "run" in bundle.js
```

So as mentioned in the answer it is must, and after this- you must execute the command:

```
npm start
```

This command will regenerate the *bundle.js* and will not include/require the *"run"* module which we were using while development. After this- you can deploy the latest bundle.js to the server.

**Tip 2:** In *webpack.config* inside *`output:{...}`* section you should set *`path`* and *`publicPath`* to a new directory i.e. */public/*. Otherwise on *Firebase* host when you mentioned 'public' directory as default directory to deploy - then it will create problem and application will not run on Firebase server.

*Note: actually I am not sure and do not know how to tell firebase to use files on my root and not in my 'public' folder* 
But I think that outputting the Webpack generated files and keeping other public files (`css, html`) inside public folder is good as otherwise *firebase deploy* may upload other files sitting in root directory as well. (correct me if I'm wrong).

Ok so finally when you are updated the *webpack.config* output values as:

`output: {
    path: __dirname+ '/public',
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }`

Then (finally making sure you are done with Tip.1 as well) and run the command to get latest bundle.js

```
npm start
```

. And finally you are good to go and deploy using:

```
firebase deploy
```

I believe you may have followed the initial steps of initiating `firebase login` and other init commands before running last deploy command.

Note: The `"firebase serve"` command is also helpful to debug and test if application is running well on local machine then it will run well on live Firebase server as well.