# Hosting React Web App bundled with webpack

Tags: reactjs, deployment, firebase, webpack, firebase-hosting

I am trying to deploy and followed your way of adding webpack dependencies but it is still showing blank in browser. I am uploading `BUNDLE.JS`, `INDEX.HTML`, `PACKAGE.JSON`, `.BABELRC`. (All file names are in lowercase).

Wondering what I am missing. My webpack generates `bundle.js` on root directory and now, as Firebase creates public directory and I am putting all above mentioned files manually in that public folder so I can deploy. Can someone tell me what are the changes required for me to make and what are the actually required files to be uploaded to Firebase.

Comment: I have checked these links also but does not work for me. I can provide more details if needed.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583858/hosting-web-app-bundled-with-webpack
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39067875/firebase-hosting-react-with-webpack

Comment: does this run fine locally?

Comment: Yes my application runs pretty well. I am sending mentioning the zip package of my directory without node_modules: [Download App](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B56dwGgpj-hBdUU4VGctMHoxelk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What @sergiomeza88 mentioned is also good to cross match but here are some additional details which solved my problem and will help a lot to others as well.

**Tip 1:**
When you deploy the application on *Firebase* and try to access browser (especially *React,Redux*) application you may get an error saying :

```
can not find module "run" in bundle.js
```

So as mentioned in the answer it is must, and after this- you must execute the command:

```
npm start
```

This command will regenerate the *bundle.js* and will not include/require the *"run"* module which we were using while development. After this- you can deploy the latest bundle.js to the server.

**Tip 2:** In *webpack.config* inside *`output:{...}`* section you should set *`path`* and *`publicPath`* to a new directory i.e. */public/*. Otherwise on *Firebase* host when you mentioned 'public' directory as default directory to deploy - then it will create problem and application will not run on Firebase server.

*Note: actually I am not sure and do not know how to tell firebase to use files on my root and not in my 'public' folder* 
But I think that outputting the webpack generated files and keeping other public files (`css,html`) inside public folder is good as otherwise *firebase deploy* may upload other files sitting in root directory as well. (correct me if I'm wrong).

Ok so finally when you are updated the *webpack.config* output values as:

`output: {
    path: __dirname+ '/public',
    publicPath: '/public/',
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  }`

Then (finally making sure you are done with Tip.1 as well) and run the command to get latest bundle.js

```
npm start
```

. And finally you are good to go and deploy using:

```
firebase deploy
```

I believe you may have followed the initial steps of initiating `firebase login` and other init commands before running last deploy command.

Note: The `"firebase serve"` command is also helpful to debug and test if application is running well on local machine then it will run well on live Firebase server as well.

Comment: When dealing with `Firebase` hosting, I use to delete old deployments, in order to let my recent/latest deployed version to work. Don't know why it is so, but it works for me.  Might be there is any cache type issue.

Answer (score 1):

You should first run the command webpack, then you need to point out the result of the webpack folder bundle in my case was dist folder in the firebase.json

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "dist",
    "rewrites": [
      {
        "source": "**",
        "destination": "/index.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

run the command **firebase deploy** and the app should be working just fine in the previous selected firebase app on the **firebase init** command.